# docker doesn't use IP from defined pool when creating new networks

Tags: docker, networking, ip

To avoid conflicts, I want to use a defined range of subnets for the `docker0` bridge and all interfaces dynamically created by the docker deamon when a new container is started.

After a quick look in the docker documentation I found the promising **fixed-cidr** option. I added this option to my daemon.json. My configuration looks as follows:

`/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.89.1/22",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.89.2/24"
}
```

after restarting the docker deamon the configuration looks promising:

```
docker inspect bridge

[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "365e0d373bcfc82bc73c623d680dcaee773e247f631e5b2324e3b63401bcf6fd",
        "Created": "2018-03-19T09:59:22.20439309+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.89.1/22",
                    "IPRange": "192.168.89.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.89.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

But for some reason, when I create a new network:

```
docker network create test-network
```

it gets a new address from default IP range:

```
docker inspect test-network
[
    {
        "Name": "test-network",
        "Id": "bf0f6baa8239c73a9524f8a77035bc2be18a67ad4d0d2ba4f73b3d175f5315b3",
        "Created": "2018-03-19T10:31:24.450183553+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

For now, I have a temporary solutation. I'll simply define a custom subnet in my docker-compose.yml

```
yaml
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.89.2/24
```

But this leads to further problems as a cannot start the project multiple times on the same hosts, because of network conflicts.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

**Edit:**
It seems to be a missing feature in docker. [Github Issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21776)

Fortunately this feature has been committed to master branch some days ago: [Committed feature](https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/commit/0ae9b6f38f24f65567d4b46602502b33c95cf57a#diff-def8fd71217e3995c71d711614a5399f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In new docker releases there is the `default-address-pools` option.

Comment: Documentation of this feature can be found at https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/dockerd.md
search for `--default-address-pool` and `default-address-pools`

Answer (score 0):

Network options in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` only work for the default `docker0` bridge.

You can specify network options when creating new networks, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

Comment: Hmm, OK but the network configuration doesn't work for new networks created by 
`docker-compose up`
either.

Comment: Yes, you should manually specify the options, in order to keep them consistent.

Comment: Manually define them with the networks section in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Either define them in docker-compose.yml, or in cli command: docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.89.1/22 --ip-range=192.168.89.0/24 --gateway=192.168.89.1 test-network

Comment: When I define them by hand (e.g. docker-compose.yml), I cannot run the same containers multiple times on the same host because of the static IP (thats my current situation).
Our buildserver should be able to launch containers multiple times and shouldn't care about IP's. That is IMHO the default behaviour. I just want to define the range of IP's the docker deamon select new IP's from. With the default IP's there are some conflicts with our production network.